# invalid xml attribute in jquery json response

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to get data from a different server. For this, I am using an authentication method using jquery. The data that should be received from that server, should be in the json format, but I am getting the following error, in the firebug (invalid XML attribute value).

Following are my requirements:
1) In order to authenticate, the params are provided as in the code below. By providing the same params within the remote server directly, I am able to get the authentication true value. But while passing the same request from this app, it's giving me Invalid xml attribute.
**Error in Firebug console**
    Search JServer Json Testing Page
    Json Input:

2) I want to get the response from that remote server in json format

Any help, will be highly appreciated.

Following is the code, within the html file.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang='en'>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.js">
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('form').submit(function() {
alert("within submit");  
alert(    $(this).attr('method'));
var url =     $(this).attr('action')
var userName =     $("#username").val();
var password =     $("#password").val();
var params = '{"token": "","messages": [{"props": {"type": "Auth","id"00001","user":' + '"' + userName + '"' + "," + '"pass":' + '"' + password + '" }}]}'
alert(url);
alert(params);
  $.get(url,params, function(data) {  
   alert("1111");
},
"jsonp" );
 return false
});

})

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="login-details">
<form id="contact" action="remote_server_url" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="text" />
<br />
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="text" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" />
</div>
</form>
<div id="first-page">    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take another look at `params`.

Comment: params seems to be correct, as thr params coming in the alert, when pasted onto the remote-server is fetching the result correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try using getjson(). this will return the json as object.

```
$.getJSON(url,params,function(data) {
alert(data);
})
;
```

Comment: Tried using that too, but in vain.